# Normalizing Python dictionary to fit database table structure

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample Data**

Suppose I have a Python dictionary stored in a variable as such:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 7)

survey_resp = {'responses': [
           {'values': {'QID1_1': 4,
                       'QID1_2': 13,
                       'QID2': 1,
                       '_recordId': 'R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR',
                       'status': 1,
                       'userLanguage': 'EN'}},
           {'values': {'QID2': 4,
                       'QID3': 1,
                       '_recordId': 'R_Zm0ZvwqeqwetSBBT',
                       'status': 0,
                       'userLanguage': 'EN'}},
           {'values': {'QID4_TEXT': 'test comment a',
                       'QID5_TEXT': 'test comment b',
                       'QID6_TEXT': 'test comment c',
                       'QID7_TEXT': 'test comment d',
                       '_recordId': 'R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe',
                       'status': 0,
                       'userLanguage': 'EN'}}]}
```

each `values` key in the `responses` list contains a dict of questions (key) and the corresponding answers (value) pertaining to a particular `_recordId`. The question keys are `QID1_1`, `QID1_2`, `QID4_TEXT`, etc.

**Problem**

Because of the way the questions and answers are all compacted into one dictionary, running `json_normalize(survey_resp['responses'])` expectedly returns each question into it's own column, which would result in terrible database design:

```
   values.QID1_1  values.QID1_2  values.QID2  ...      values._recordId  values.status values.userLanguage
0            4.0           13.0          1.0  ...      R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR              1                  EN 
1            NaN            NaN          4.0  ...    R_Zm0ZvwqeqwetSBBT              0                  EN 
2            NaN            NaN          NaN  ...  R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe              0                  EN
```

**Question**

What would be the most efficient way to dynamically transform this data into a structure that is fit for loading into a normalized database such that each question and answer gets its own row with the corresponding recordId, status, userLanguage etc. in the database? Surely nested loops to restructure the dicts isn't the only solution to something like this?

**Expected Output**

```
   values.question  values.question_answer  ...      values._recordId  values.status values.userLanguage
0           QID1_1                       4  ...      R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR              1                  EN
1           QID1_2                      13  ...      R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR              1                  EN
2             QID2                       1  ...      R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR              1                  EN
3             QID2                       4  ...      R_Zm0ZvwqeqwetSBBT            0                  EN
4             QID3                       1  ...      R_Zm0ZvwqeqwetSBBT            0                  EN
5        QID4_TEXT        'test comment a'  ...      R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe          0                  EN
6        QID5_TEXT        'test comment b'  ...      R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe          0                  EN
7        QID6_TEXT        'test comment c'  ...      R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe          0                  EN
8        QID7_TEXT        'test comment d'  ...      R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe          0                  EN
```

The question answer is only present if the user answered the question so not all question answers will be present. Other values such as recordId, status, userLanguage etc. will always be present in a response.

Comment: Are the `'responses', 'values', '_recordId', 'status', 'userLanguage'` keys static?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary structure is static with respect to the `'responses', 'values', '_recordId', 'status', 'userLanguage'` keys - so those can be *hard-coded*.

Extract the `'values'` values from the `'responses'` key; pop the *common* items from those results; append the common item values to the remaining items; store in a container that can be fed to Pandas.

```
d = survey_resp
values = operator.itemgetter('values')
r = d['responses']
rows = []
for thing in map(values, r):
    (r_id,status,userLang) = thing.pop('_recordId'),thing.pop('status'),thing.pop('userLanguage')
    for item in thing.items():
        row = item + (r_id,status,userLang)
#        print(row)
        rows.append(row)
#    print('****************')
```

---

```
In [10]: rows
Out[10]: 
[('QID1_1', 4, 'R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR', 1, 'EN'),
 ('QID1_2', 13, 'R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR', 1, 'EN'),
 ('QID2', 1, 'R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR', 1, 'EN'),
 ('QID2', 4, 'R_Zm0ZvwqeqwetSBBT', 0, 'EN'),
 ('QID3', 1, 'R_Zm0ZvwqeqwetSBBT', 0, 'EN'),
 ('QID4_TEXT', 'test comment a', 'R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe', 0, 'EN'),
 ('QID5_TEXT', 'test comment b', 'R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe', 0, 'EN'),
 ('QID6_TEXT', 'test comment c', 'R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe', 0, 'EN'),
 ('QID7_TEXT', 'test comment d', 'R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe', 0, 'EN')]

In [17]: columns = ['question','question_answer','recordId','status','userLanguage']

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

In [19]: print(df)
    question question_answer              recordId  status userLanguage
0     QID1_1               4      R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR       1           EN
1     QID1_2              13      R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR       1           EN
2       QID2               1      R_3L6WGfdsfsdNBR       1           EN
3       QID2               4    R_Zm0ZvwqeqwetSBBT       0           EN
4       QID3               1    R_Zm0ZvwqeqwetSBBT       0           EN
5  QID4_TEXT  test comment a  R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe       0           EN
6  QID5_TEXT  test comment b  R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe       0           EN
7  QID6_TEXT  test comment c  R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe       0           EN
8  QID7_TEXT  test comment d  R_1d01j456hgfgh26oVe       0           EN
```

---

As for efficiency, it is more efficient than something that doesn't work.

Comment: It's not static in that `survey_resp['responses'][2]` could have for example `'QID1_2': 7` if the user had answered that question. Only questions that were answered on the front-end will be populated in the dict as key value pairs.